# How to view all nested dependencies of a package in ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Can someone let me know how can I view all the nested dependencies of a package in Ubuntu? For example,

```
support@vrni-platform:/tmp$ sudo apt-cache depends hadoop-yarn-resourcemanager
hadoop-yarn-resourcemanager
  Depends: hadoop-yarn

support@vrni-platform:/tmp$ sudo apt-cache depends hadoop-yarn
hadoop-yarn
  Depends: libc6
  Depends: adduser
  Depends: bigtop-utils
  Depends: hadoop
  Depends: avro-libs
  Depends: zookeeper
```

I am looking for something like below. Somewhat similar to `mvn dependency:tree`

```
hadoop-yarn-resourcemanager
  Depends: hadoop-yarn
     Depends: libc6
     Depends: adduser
     Depends: bigtop-utils
     Depends: hadoop
     Depends: avro-libs
     Depends: zookeeper
```

I have seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4627158/how-to-list-all-dependencies-of-a-package-on-linux) but I am looking for complete dependency tree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, there is the `apt-cache dotty` command, which will generate a graphviz representation of the package's dependencies.  However, this is going to be less useful than you think: there are a lot of "core packages" that are going to be required by just about everything, and the resulting graphs will be quite large.

For example, the output of `apt-cache dotty openssh-client` renders into [this beast](http://chunk.io/larsks/4389cce4d67c40f98889634f5e537fe8).

The dot syntax is relatively simple; you could probably parse that yourself to  extract a subset of the information.

Comment: there are many options that help make `depends` (but strangely not  `dotty`) a bit more lean like `apt-cache -o APT::Cache::RecurseDepends=true -o APT::Cache::ShowOnlyFirstOr=true -o APT::Cache::ShowSuggests=false -o APT::Cache::ShowRecommends=false -o APT::Cache::ShowReplaces=false -o APT::Cache::ShowConflicts=false -o APT::Cache::ShowBreaks=false -o APT::Cache::ShowEnhances=false depends FOO` . That will at least prevent a recursive depends on iptables from showing libreoffice.

Answer (score 5):

This question is quite old, however apt-cache currently has a `--recurse` option for `depends` and `rdepends` that makes this easy:

`apt-cache depends -i --recurse <packagename>`

You probably also want the `-i` as that limits output to actual `Depends:`, filtering out non-essentials like `Recommends:` and `Suggests:`.

With the above options, the output can be enormous as it will include every package down to the kernel itself! With simple packages this might be no big deal, but for a desktop environment or even a large application...

Comment: Thanks. I extend a bit further to this `apt-cache depends -i --recurse <pkg_name> | awk -F 'Depends: ' 'NF>1{ sub(/ .*/,"",$NF); print $NF }' | sort | uniq`

Comment: @TuanAnhTran - Beware, that looks like it will obscure alternate dependencies. Try it with `libssl3` and it you'll get both `debconf` and `<debconf-2.0>` listed, when in reality you only need one or the other...

Comment: Thanks. How do i filter those out?

Comment: @TuanAnhTran - that's the conundrum - you don't want to filter them out. What to do depends on your use case. If you intend to simply display the output, then you would need to identify these instances of alternative dependencies. The output  from `apt-cache` has already been formatted in a simplified manner, with provisions to show these nuances - aside from format preference, there isn't really a simpler way.